# trim function is giving unexpected values php

Tags: php, trim

I have taken the following inputs

```
$file  = 'D:/php/testapp/ta_bles.json';
$table = trim(end(explode("/", $file)), '.json');
```

but instead of giving `ta_bles` as the output it is giving `ta_ble`
can any one help me what is happening

but when i use the following logic it gave expected results

```
$table = str_replace('.json', '', end(explode("/", $file)));
```

Comment: Have a look at what the second argument for `trim` actually means.

Comment: the problem  is happening only when i am having an underscore in the name

Comment: After the edit, @Gumbo was spot-on with what the problem was (see [the docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php)). If he doesn't write an answer, I'll do it shortly.

Comment: @Gumbo, thanks for your input i got it now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why it doesn't work as expected is because the second argument to [`trim()`](http://php.net/trim) (and related functions) is used as a character set; so in the extreme example of `"json.json"` you will end up with an empty string because it trims each character separately.

You could compare such an operation to this:

```
preg_replace('/^[.json]+|[.json]+$/', '', $str);
```

To just get `"tables"` you should use [`pathinfo()`](http://php.net/pathinfo) instead of trying to roll your own:

```
$table = pathinfo('d:/php/testapp/tables.json', PATHINFO_FILENAME);
```