# ltrim stripping more than it should from string php

Tags: php

```
var_dump($this->view_path); // app/views/admin
var_dump(ltrim( $this->view_path, 'app/views/')); // dmin/
```

Why `ltrim` strips more than `app/views/`, where is my `a` from `admin/`?

Comment: `string ltrim ( string $str [, string $character_mask ] )` [see manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ltrim.php): *Simply list all characters that you want to be stripped*. Your's are: `a` `p` `/` `v` `i` `e` `w` `s`

Comment: Your title *"rtrim stripping more..."* is contradictive to your posted code `ltrim`. Edit: Oh, that's been changed now. As per http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/32361407/1

Comment: Explained in this earlier question's accepted answer: https://stackoverflow.com/q/23075343/2943403  Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/40115894/2943403

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second parameter of `ltrim` is the character mask, not an string to be remove from another. You have the character a in your mask, so it removes it. But you don't have d, so it finished the trim there.

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the other answer, `ltrim` is not the right method for this. It's stripping all of the characters you listed, no matter where they are located in the string.

`preg_replace` will trim the known value from the beginning of the string:

```
 preg_replace('/^app\/views\//', '', $this->view_path); // admin
```

Comment: yes I did like that after, didn't want to use `preg_replace` for simple string removing, as it is performant cost, alternative would be `substr` but then again I would have to account for a string length once it changes.. also I think you can't use slashes as delimiters, but some other char like `#`

Comment: @branquito dunno what machine you're on, but [here 1000 loops finish in ~0.002 sec](https://eval.in/427045).

Comment: I got 0.001 :). I think loops do not add overhead to a performance, as once the preg match has been found it's compiled and cached I suppose?

Comment: @branquito I agree, that `substr`, `strpos`,... are of better performance but doing a `^`start-anchored replace with `preg_replace` is no effort for the regex parser. Well, happy benchmarking :]