# How to remove the first two directories from a file path string?

Tags: php, filepath, substr

I have a string  "./product_image/Bollywood/1476813695.jpg".

first I remove . from first.

now I want to remove all character between first two / . that means I want

```
Bollywood/1476813695.jpg
```

I am trying with this but not work

```
substr(strstr(ltrim('./product_image/Bollywood/1476813695.jpg', '.'),"/product_image/"), 1);
```

It always return `product_image/Bollywood/1476813695.jpg`

Comment: explode("/", $string); then you have an array an can take the parts you need

Comment: Maybe `str_replace("./","/",$string)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove root directory from a directory path string - PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9696977/remove-root-directory-from-a-directory-path-string-php)

Answer (score 4):

Easily done with `explode()`:

```
$orig = './product_image/Bollywood/1476813695.jpg';
$origArray = explode('/', $orig);
$new = $origArray[2] . '/' . $origArray[3];
```

result:

> Bollywood/1476813695.jpg

If you want something a little different you can use regex with `preg_replace()`

```
$pattern = '/\.\/(.*?)\//';
$string = './product_image/Bollywood/1476813695.jpg';
$new = preg_replace($pattern, '', $string);
```

This returns the same thing and you could, if you wanted, put it all in one line.

Comment: Cleaner with different pattern delimiters and less escaping, Jay.

Answer (score 2):

```
$str = "./product_image/Bollywood/1476813695.jpg";

$str_array = explode('/', $str);

$size = count($str_array);

$new_string = $str_array[$size - 2] . '/' . $str_array[$size - 1];

echo $new_string;
```

Comment: This answer is missing its educational explanation.

Answer (score 1):

please follow the below code

```
$newstring = "./product_image/Bollywood/1476813695.jpg";
$pos =substr($newstring, strpos($newstring, '/', 2)+1);
var_dump($pos);
```

and output will be looking

> Bollywood/1476813695.jpg

for strpos function detail please go to below link

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php

for substr position detail please go to below link

http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php